# Ubuntu vs. Debian SSH public key login

Tags: ssh, ubuntu, debian, public-key

In the Debian 9 server I have, these are the least restrictive permissions I can set for SSH login with public key to work:

```
/home/user                          775
/home/user/.ssh                     775
/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys     644
```

Any less restrictive permissions results in `SSH` asking passwords.

But in my Ubuntu 20, any permissions work for `SSH`. What is the reason for this? Is there a security feature that should be enabled in Ubuntu? Indeed the guard in Debian makes sense. When one set group writes permissions for `authorized_keys`, it can be easily compromised by other users.

Comment: I'm unable to recreate your results in Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.  authorized_keys is originally set to 600, changing to to 644 still allows login.  Changing it to 666 breaks login.  Making .ssh world writeable (from 700 -> 702) breaks login.

Comment: I'm guessing `StrictMode` is set to `no` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: @kenlukas it is `StrictModes` thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default, permissions for `~/.ssh` must be limited to the user in question. I don't think this has changed in the history of OpenSSH or its packages for Debian or Ubuntu.

This is controlled by `StrictModes` documented in `man 5 sshd_config` (for your versions in question, see [Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal) docs](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/sshd_config.5.html) vs [Debian 9 (Stretch) docs](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/openssh-server/sshd_config.5.en.html)). This section is identical between those two:

> **StrictModes**
> Specifies whether `sshd(8)` should check file modes and ownership of the user's files and home directory before accepting login.  This is normally desirable because novices sometimes accidentally leave their directory or files world-writable.  The default is `yes`.  Note that this does not apply to `ChrootDirectory`, whose permissions and ownership are checked unconditionally.

My best guess is that your Ubuntu system has been configured to set `StrictModes no`, which is strongly discouraged. I suggest changing it back to `yes`.

It is best for `~/.ssh` directories to be mode 0700 (`drwx------`) and home directories to be writable only by their owners  (so `~/.ssh` isn't overwritten). I don't think the permissions on `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` matter since only you and root can even see that it exists, but it's still best to keep at 600 (`-rw-------`) or 644 (`-rw-r--r--`).

Comment: Thanks. Setting `StrictModes` to `yes` fixed it. It's strange why the VPS provider has commented this line. Or is this default behavior in Ubuntu?

Comment: Definitely not the default on Ubuntu or Debian. I'm guessing your VPS provider did it to address some permissioning issue with their provisioning scripts.